# File listing in SFTP doesn't synchronise

Tags: files, sftp

I have a SFTP account that I use to store files. It works fine, but when I am using `lftp` on connection A to look at the files, and connection B to store files, connection A does not reflect any changes made by connection B.

When I log in again, it does show the files.

Is this a setting, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `rels` command  will display the directory entries ignoring anything cached. Alternately, `cache flush` will clear the cache and `cache off` will turn it off.

Answer (score 3):

The SFTP protocol does not include a way for the server to tell your client A "hey, the directory has been updated".

If your client A caches the directory listing after downloading the listing once, you need to check the documentation of the SFTP client to find out how to tell the SFTP client to download the directory listing again (in WinSCP or similar SFTP clients, it might be <kbd>F5</kbd> or the `Refresh` button/menu item).

Comment: In WinSCP, in the default Commander interface, the shortcut is actually `Ctrl+R`.